# how to use StatusCallback url in twilio

Tags: twilio

```
<?php
$options = array(
  "StatusCallback" => 'http://173.203.104.63/call/out/log-callback.php?  id='.$id
);

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);
try {
  // Initiate a new outbound call
  $call = $client->account->calls->create(
    $phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
    $cphonenumber, // The number of the phone receiving call
    '60',
    'http://173.203.104.63/call/out/three.php?id='.$id, // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered
    $options
  );
...
```

here i have set up url for statuscallback but i dont know weather it is redirecting or not and also how to get my callstatus values in that url

Comment: Hi, The `StatusCallback` URL will only be requested when the call is done. You should use the `Url` to request that url when the call connects. You should be able to tell which URL was requested in your Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd argument should be the URL, not `'60'`. Once the call ends, all the data will be passed to your callback URL as normal `POST` or `GET` parameters (depending on what you've setup in your account).

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to specify the method for statuscallback url

i have included it here in the code

```
    <?php
//"StatusCallbackMethod" can be "POST" or "GET", depends on the way you recieve it on your StatusCallback,
    $options = array(
      "StatusCallbackMethod"=>"GET",
      "StatusCallback" => 'http://173.203.104.63/call/out/log-callback.php?  id='.$id
    );

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);
try {
  // Initiate a new outbound call
  $call = $client->account->calls->create(
    $phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
    $cphonenumber, // The number of the phone receiving call
    '60',
    'http://173.203.104.63/call/out/three.php?id='.$id, // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered
    $options
  );
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); //  

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
$token = "{{ auth_token }}";
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$call = $client->account->calls->create("+18668675309", "+14155551212",      "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", array(
    "Method" => "GET",
   "StatusCallback" => "https://www.myapp.com/events",
   "StatusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
   "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"),
));
echo $call->sid;
```

Please see https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

Comment: Why should one look there? Because the posted code is copied from Example 4? What does it do? How do you think it helps? Whats the crucial point to the OP's code?